# How to push an item to an array and get the index of that item in MongoDB, Projection in find_one_and_update pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

I'd like to $push an item into an array and determine the index at which it was inserted. How can I do this with Mongo?

I need this to be atomic as multiple pushes can be happening in parallel on the document.

I'm using Python/PyMongo as the driver.

Answer (score 2):

You can store the size of the array along with the array within the document and get that value after the update:

Sample input document: `{ '_id: 1', 'arr': [ "apple", "orange" ] }`

The update operation - uses a pipeline for the *update* (available with MongoDB version 4.2):

```
NEW_ITEM = 'pear'

r = collection.find_one_and_update(
  { '_id': 1 },
  [
    { 
      '$set': { 
        'ix': { '$size': '$arr' }, 
        'arr': { '$concatArrays': [ '$arr', [ NEW_ITEM ] ] } 
      } 
    }
  ],
  projection = { '_id': False, 'ix': True }, 
  return_document = ReturnDocument.AFTER
)
```

Another way is set the index of the newly inserted element within the same update operation (this can be used if array elements are unique):

```
  [
    { 
      '$set': { 
        'arr': { '$concatArrays': [ '$arr', [ NEW_ITEM ] ] } 
      },
      '$set': { 
        'ix': { '$indexOfArray': [ '$arr', NEW_ITEM ] } 
      }
    }
  ]
```

Comment: Looks good, but how do I know the size is taken after updating the array (or is taken before)?

Comment: The update operation is **atomic** - it doesn't matter how many fields, arrays. embedded objects are newly created or updated or removed from the existing document.

Answer (score 1):

Updates to a single document in MongoDB are [atomic](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/write-operations-atomicity/), So if one update operation is writing to a document the following update operation has to wait until the first one finishes. So you can return the updated document & in code get the index of the newly pushed value(As `$push` will usually push to end of the array).

So when you use MongoDB's aggregation framework for reads - You can use [$indexOfArray](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/indexOfArray/index.html) operator with `$project` stage to get the index of an element in an array. But projection is aggregation framework can accept lot more operators than projection in `.find()`'s or `.findOneAndUpdate()`'s. Getting index of an element in an array might not be possible with update operations, So using below query you can return the complete new array from updated document & using python try to get the index of element in new array.

**Sample Doc :**

```
{
  _id: ObjectId("5eb773b8c4ec53c0626b167e"),
  name: "YesMe",
  ids: [1, 2, 3],
};
```

**Query :**

```
db.collection.find_one_and_update(
  { name: "YesMe" },
  { $push: { ids: 4 } },
  (projection = { ids: True, _id: False }), // Projecting only `ids` field
  (return_document = ReturnDocument.AFTER) // Returns updated doc (In your case updated array)
);
```

**Output :**

```
{ ids : [1, 2, 3, 4] }
```

**Ref :** [Collection.find_one_and_update](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/collection.html?highlight=find_one_and_update#pymongo.collection.Collection.find_one_and_update)